# htaccess redirect, everything is redirecting instead of specific requests

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to setup a new project structure. Due to some limitations of my cloud provider, I need to do some htaccess magic which I'm struggling with.

The project structure is as following

/docroot => Contains my Drupal installation
/docroot/frontend => Contains an Angular frontend
/docroot/pim => Is a symlink to /docroot.

What we need is that when we surf to example.com/pim that it redirects to the Drupal docroot /docroot. Since due to limitations of the cloud provider we can't put it in the /pim folder, they suggested to make a symlink.

Any other request to example.com should go to docroot/frontend.

So I've added the following code in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend.*$
RewriteRule !^pim($|/) http://example.com/frontend%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Current behaviour is that all requests go to /frontend/index.php (I think the index.php comes from the .htaccess of Drupal, so the redirect is not done cleanely) While I would expect a request to example.com/test to direct to example.com/frontend/test
Also example.com/pim points to example.com/frontend/index.php instead of staying in the /pim directory

Comment: What you wrote is - if url has frontend in it redirect it to frontend...
http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite check these examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to fix it. :)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pim.*$
RewriteRule ^ frontend%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend.*$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```